# Does the order of the tables in the INNER JOINs and the FROM clause matter?

Tags: sql-server, processing-efficiency

So assume you perform an inner join between table1 and table2 on column1
Does it make a difference if the table with lower entries is in the FROM-clause?

So you start with less results in the first place and then the Join will reduce it less than the other way around.

Same thing for multiple INNER JOINs, should you put the JOINs first that will reduce the results the most, so the following joins have less work? Or does it not follow an procesing order?

Comment: It's always good practice to construct your joins correctly, filtering rows as early as possible, in most cases the query optimizer will reorder your joins based on its own assumptions of data estimates and cardinality.

Comment: Of course. From the performance aspect it matters. Table with lower data or table that will filter in WHERE clause should come first.

Comment: @MeyssamToluie Utter nonsense

Comment: It *may* make a difference if there are so many joins that the optimizer can't work out a proper order (in the sense that the ultimate order may change based on your order, *not* that your order is the one used), normally it doesn't. Even in the case where you figure out a better order than the optimizer (or think you have) you would need an explicit `FORCE ORDER` hint to make the optimizer use that order, rather than whatever it has calculated the most effective order is (and normally, you want to tune indexes and statistics so the proper order pops out, instead of doing that).